# Why does nested list comprehension for class attribute fail?

Tags: python, class, list-comprehension

When running class code:

```
class foo():
    r = 2
    c = 2
    a = [[0 for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
    print(a)

foo()
```

This error is generated:

> NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Though both `r` and `c` are show if using the `locals()` call after the definitions.

Admittingly a little bit weird, but still code encountered in real life :-)

**Why is the `c` variable not visible in the inner list comprehension?**

---

For comparison, when running this function code:

```
def foo():
    r = 2
    c = 2
    print(locals())
    a = [[0 for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
    print(a)

foo()
```

The expected result is shown:

> [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

Both `r` and `c` are also show if using the `locals()` call after the definitions.